# How to pass input Parameters to Cybersoursegateway in Android?

Tags: android, browser, android-webview, payment-gateway

I am developing one application related to **Cynersource payment gateway**. But i have     small doubt to calling Cybersource site which is the better way to call Cybersource payment     site that is using webview or directly redirecting to browser.

This is the url i used for redirecting to Cybersource..

**https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/pay**

Is there any params required to call this URL. Because it shows some error while calling this URL that is **"It is possible that the requested page no longer exists"**.

Please check the below image.....

[image]

After completion of payment i want to redirect to my application again....

Please help me anyone.

Thanks in Advance......

Answer (score 0):

yes there are a few parameters that you will have to supply in your request to https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/pay.

It depends on the connection method (Secure Acceptance SOP or Secure Acceptance WM) and basically on what kind of inforamtion you already have and what you want to send. Check these manuals: http://www.cybersource.com/developers/develop/integration_methods/secure_acceptance/

Roughly saying you have to send your identifier, order details and the payment details, and you have to calculate the signature.

Both manuals btw have sample code included. Hope it helps!